# A problem on complex analysis Maximum Modulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f  :  (\bar{\Bbb D}) \rightarrow \Bbb C $ be a non constant function continuous in $ (\bar{\Bbb D}) $ and analytic in $ \Bbb D $

Show that if $ |f(z)-1|=1 $ for each $z$ st $ |z|=1 $ there is no $z \in \Bbb D $ such that $f(z)=0$

where $ \Bbb D $ is the unit circle centred on zero.

I tried using $g=f(z)-1$ and use its analyticity but couldn't find a contradiction assuming there is a point where $f(z)=0$

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Consider $g(z) = f(z) - 1$, then we have $|g(z)| = 1$ for $|z| = 1$.

If there is one point $z_0 \in D$ such that $f(z_0) = 0$, then we have $|g(z_0)| = 1$.

Consider the maximum of $|g(z)|$ on $\bar{D}$, it's reached either at some other point inside $D$ such that the maximal value of $|g(z)|$ is strictly greater than $1$, or it's reached at $z_0$ such that the maximal value of $|g(z)|$ is equal to $1$.

In both case, by [maximum modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle), $g$ is constant, i.e. $f$ is constant

Comment: Thanks the issue I had was that you can say g is constant in $ \Bbb D $ and $|g(z)|=1$ everywhere does that directly imply that g is constant on the boundary?